# grafana prometheus use legend from other series

Tags: grafana, prometheus

have the following series and want use `host[host]` for legend instead of `instance`. can anyone help?

first one:

- `node_load1{instance=~"$node"}`
- `node_load1{instance="10.42.220.165:9100",job="HostsMetrics"}`

and the second one:

- `host{instance=~"$node"}`
- `host{host="srv02.example.com",instance="10.42.220.165:9100",job="HostsMetrics",node="Prometheus-node-exporter-2"}`

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are searching for [vector matching](https://prometheus.io/docs/querying/operators/#vector-matching). There is a nice blog post by Robust Perception about it [here](https://www.robustperception.io/how-to-have-labels-for-machine-roles/) which seems to describes the solution to your problem.

In short, assuming that the second metric always has a value of 1 you should be able to do something like this:

```
node_load1{instance=~"$node"} * ON (instance) group_left(host) host{instance=~"$node"}
```

This would basically add the host label from the host metric to your resulting vector.

Hope that helps.

In case you need more labels added to the resulting vector just add it to the `group_left(host)` part like `group_left(host, node)`.